# Update observable from promise based on other observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service which returns filters from our backend. This service has a method `getForPage` which returns a promise, and a `getForPage$` which returns an observable.

On the service there is also the method `onEvent` which is an observable which emits when there was a change on a filter.

Now I want that the `getForPage$` observable is updated when the `onEvent` emits an event. Which is done with the following code.

```
getForPage(page: string): Promise<DashboardPageFilter[]> {
    return this.service.call(
        'dashboard.page.filter.getForPage',
        {page}
    );
}

getForPage$(page: string): Observable<DashboardPageFilter[]> {
    let subject = new Subject<DashboardPageFilter[]>();

    this.getForPage(page).then(
        response => subject.next(response),
        response => subject.error(response)
    );

    this.onEvent().subscribe(() => {
        console.log(page);
        this.getForPage(page).then(
            response => subject.next(response),
            response => subject.error(response)
        );
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

However when I can the route the subscription on `onEvent` won't be closed. So the log will be called even when there is not an active subscription any more on the subject observable.

How do you make an observable from a promise which can be to be updated and is completed on route change?

Comment: You mentioned this is a part of service, why you need to unsubscribe when the service is never destroyed/deallocated?

Comment: `getForPage$()` creates a new subscription every time on the `onEvent()`. So when I placed a log in the subscription and moved a round in the app, and changed something the log was called multiple times even with old pages.

Comment: You can hold subscription `this.sub = this.onEvent().subscribe(...)` and unsubscribe when calling `getForPage()` with `this.sub.unsubscribe()`

Comment: That is a possibility and for now a nice fix. However it is not possible to call `getForPage$()` twice to show to different lists.

Comment: I don't get why you need a getForpage():Promise and a getForPage():Observable, while you can litteraly convert a promise to an observable and an observable to a promise ^^

Comment: @supamiu the `getForPage(): Promise` is used to obtain a list of filters for the page, this list is not updated and only used in the service it self actually. The `getForPage(): Observable` is used to obtain a list of the filters but is updated if a an event has occurred (`onEvent`). The list is shown in a sidebar while in the main area a filter is added/updated. So the sidebar is updated without knowledge of the main area

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `merge` operator instead:

```
getForPage$(page: string): Observable<DashboardPageFilter[]> {

    const obsFromPromise = Observable.fromPromise(this.getForPage(page));

    const result = this.onEvent.switchMap(() => Observable.fromPromise(this.getForPage(page)));

    return Observable.merge(obsFromPromise, obsFromEvent)
}
```

By doing this, your promise and your event are merged into one observable with no subscription.

More details about the merge operator are available on [rxjs documentation website](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html).

Comment: The `onEvent` notifies that there is a change it does not contain the filters. So the promise has to be recalled. So unfortunately your solution does not work

Comment: @MKroeders Oh I see, just have to add an operator on obsFromEvent to map the void result to promise one and that's it :) going to add this a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

After more attempts to fix the issue, some ideas from the comments and a relook at the code I came to a solution for the problem. However this still has an other minor issue

Before the code was living outside the observable for updating. With the code below the updating live inside the observer.

```
return Observable.create((observer: Observer<DashboardPageFilter[]>) => {
    this.getForPage(page).then(
        response => observer.next(response),
        response => observer.error(response)
    );

    let sub = this.onEvent().subscribe(() => {
        console.log(page);
        this.getForPage(page).then(
            response => observer.next(response),
            response => observer.error(response)
        );
    });

    return function () {
        sub.unsubscribe();
    };
});
```

The main thing is the callback, which cancels the subscription on unsubscribe.

However in angular you need a route change to an other route (so not the same with different parameters) before the unsubscribe is called.